# flutter build ipa fail with profile

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, ipa

if i try to do flutter build ipa i got the error:

```
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 2TPRUM2A9L
Running Xcode build...
Xcode archive done.                                          3,3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[10019]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x203eb2b90) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1084e42c8). One of the two
    will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[10019]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x203eb2be0) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1084e4318). One of the two
    will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** ARCHIVE FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    error: No profiles for 'com.fahrschuleplaner24' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning
    profiles matching 'com.fahrschuleplaner24'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable
    automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

in xcode on signing & capabilities

[image]

No profiles for 'com.fahrschuleplaner24' were found

[image]

im the owner of the account and also i have this profile there but still it wont work

please help me to solve it

Comment: Look at the warning you have inside Xcode.

Comment: yeah i know, but what can i do? i have already there a profile i dont know why it wont connect or whatever

Comment: You are missing an application developer profile (check your apple developer platform) and you don't have a device registered as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to run it on a real iphone, after that it worked

Comment: correct you have to register at least one real device

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this once. first clear DerivedData for xcode and then try following commands

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter pub get`
3. `cd ios`
4. `pod install`
5. `pod update`

now after this open with xcode and check

Comment: still the same error